# How to handle exceptions and error in apache camel route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, azure-blob-storage, camel-ftp

I have a file watcher route and azure blob container route. I would like to handle/throw exceptions and errors. Can someone assist me with some examples ?

I would like to handle cases like if there is any exception while connecting to blob container or while processing files from the directory.

```
@Override
  public void configure() {


    onException(Exception.class).handled(true)
        .setHeader(AppConstants.FILENAME , simple("${headers.camelFileName}"))
        .setHeader(AppConstants.EXCEPTION_INFO, simple("General Exception"))
        .setHeader(AppConstants.EXCEPTION_LOG, simple("${exception}"))
        .log("${exception} Exception occured while processing the file:::${in.headers.camelFileName}")
        .to("file://error")
        .end();

    onException(BlobStorageException.class).handled(true)
        .setHeader(AppConstants.CONTAINERNAME , simple("${headers.CamelAzureStorageBlobContainerName}"))
        .setHeader(AppConstants.EXCEPTION_INFO, simple("Communication Exception"))
        .setHeader(AppConstants.EXCEPTION_LOG, simple("${exception}"))
        .log("${exception} Exception occured while Connecting to Azure Blob :::${in.headers.camelFileName}")
        .to("file://error")
        .end();


  from("file-watch:hello?events=CREATE&antInclude=**/*.csv&recursive=true")
        .routeId("fileWatch")
        .log("File Consumed Name: ${header.CamelFileName}")
        .to("direct:uploadFileToBlob")
        .end();


 from("direct:uploadFileToBlob")
        .routeId("uploadFile")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"Container Name: ${header.CamelAzureStorageBlobContainerName}")
        .toD("azure-storage-blob://jdawmsdevsa/${header.CamelAzureStorageBlobContainerName}?blobName=${header.CamelFileName}&operation=uploadBlockBlob&serviceClient=#serviceClient")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"${header.CamelFileName} Uploaded to ${header.CamelAzureStorageBlobContainerName} Container Successfully")
        .end();

}
```

So far, I have handled the above General Exception and BlobStorage connectivity exceptions.Any suggestion to further enhance error and exception cases ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Route scope exceptions

Instead of using global scope for all exceptions you could use [route specific scope](https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html#_advanced_usage_of_exception_clause) instead which allows you to handle exceptions that are for example specific to your `uploadFile` route.

#### Redelivery options

With connection errors you could also configure [redelivery policy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html#_configuring_redeliverypolicy_redeliver_options) to make the route more robust against minor connectivity issues.